# Vim: Close and return to last tab, repeat

Tags: vim, tabs, vim-plugins

I find myself in this situation very often:

1. Open gVim with NERDTree from current working directory.
2. Open a file from NERDTree using `<S-T>` so it grabs a new tab.
3. `:tabprevious` to return to NERDTree.
4. Explore directories and open a second file using `<S-T>`.
5. Close the second file, `:q` or `ZZ`.

What I would have expected to happen after **5.** is to return to NERDTree, but Vim always collapses the tab and opens the one to the right. This is rarely what I intended to do and would much rather have Vim keep a list of all tabs I have cycled through. So, as I close one, it pops it off the stack and focuses the next.

This can be seen in other editors, mostly IDEs, like Komodo Edit for example.

Is there a plug-in which would do this for Vim?

Answer (score 1):

To go to the first tab (presumably the one with NERDTree open), do `:tabfirst`. Vim doesn't keep a list of tabs ordered by "most recently accessed" and `:tabprevious`/`:tabnext` only deal with the tabs on the left/right.

The default action for `T` is precisely to open the selected file in a new tab *and* come back to the tab where NERDTree is located. So I'm not sure why you have to do `:tabprevious` after `T`.

A common way to use NERDTree is to simply open it on the spot, when you need it, and set it to close itself upon opening a file. I don't remember the name of the option but a quick `:help nerdtree` would be enough.

Also I'm afraid you are making a mistake here: you are using Vim's "tabs" as if they where the same as the tabs found everywhere else. This is a bad idea because they are not designed that way at all. Instead, read up on windows and buffers.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I am fairly advanced with Vim, which should have been mentioned in the original post. If no one has indeed came across this sort of behaviour (provided by a plug-in), it would make for a good weekend project.